# Error: Redirect to a localhost from a Paypal sandbox IPN

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, paypal, localhost, paypal-ipn

I have implemented a `Paypal` structure
through my page button it direct to a `paypal` sandbox,
payment being performed.

```
form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abhish_1347270213_biz@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Red Jacket" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="7601" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="125.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif" border="0"
        name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"
        height="1" />

        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="localhost:53237/WebSite17/Default.aspx" />


     <div></div>

    </form>
```

Now when i am trying to redirect to a `localhost`, its showing an error. 
I need to ask is it possible to redirect to a `localhost` from a `paypal`, and if it is possible then how shall i implement this. thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try http:// in front of the localhost

Answer (score 0):

In place of

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="localhost:53237/WebSite17/Default.aspx" />
```

place

```
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:53237/WebSite17/Default.aspx" />
```

and for IPN notification
place

```
 <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost:53237/WebSite17/Default.aspx" />
```

It will redirect to the site with the return Value `Varified`for the transaction.